# in 買っては, I need some explanation for っては part

Tags: grammar, ellipsis

Here is the reply I got after saying that I was interested in buying new shoes.

> 靴買うならTシャツやいま使うもの買っては？！

I think I got the overall meaning however I’m a bit confused with “買っては”.
I don’t really get the “っては” part.
Could you explain?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ては is short for 「～てはどう(ですか)？」, "How about doing ~~?", "Why don't you ~~?

> ～を買っ**ては**？ = ～を買っ**ては**どう(ですか)？
>   ≒ ～を買っ**たら**？　= ～を買っ**たら**どう(ですか)？

The ては in ～～てはどうですか **literally means "If~~"** (≒～たら).
(ては = the conjunctive particle て + the binding particle は).
So ～てはどうですか literally means "How is it, if you do~~?" --> "How about doing~~?"
It's definition #6 on [goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/152199/m0u/).

> 靴(を)買うならTシャツやいま使うもの(を)買っては？！

"If you're going to buy shoes, how about buying / why don't you buy a t-shirt / t-shirts or an item / items that you'll use now **instead** (rather than shoes)?"

Comment: It disturbs me that the を between 靴 and 買うis missing. Is it in general ok in Japanese to omit the を particle as we please?

Comment: Yes, two を's are omitted in your sentence. (I edited my post.) Particles such as が, を, に etc. get omitted quite often in casual/daily conversation. Eg.「コーヒー(を)ください。」「お金(が)欲しい。」「学校(に)行ってくる。」

Comment: Thank you for your help! (It's not my sentence though (^^))

Comment: @ナウシカ Oh! It was not your question! Sorry, 間違えたぁ...