# Expressing the concept of "instead"

Tags: grammar, usage

I'd have liked to have asked this as a comment to the accepted answer in the post linked below but sadly, my reputation does not yet allow that.

[in 買っては, I need some explanation for っては part](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/in-%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF-i-need-some-explanation-for-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF-part)

In the above post, the sentence

> 靴買うならTシャツやいま使うもの買っては？！

is translated as

> "If you're going to buy shoes, how about buying / why don't you buy a t-shirt / t-shirts or an item / items that you'll use now **instead** (rather than shoes)?"

I was wondering why the translator is so confident that "instead" is implied rather than "as well".  When I hear "How about..." in English, I feel at best a slight implication of "instead of the alternative". Does "どうですか" carry a strong implication of "instead" in Japanese?

Further, is there a way that the speaker could have emphasized her meaning with a specific word or expression (something like "rather than the alternatives")?

And lastly, how could the speaker have have said:

> "If you're going to buy shoes, how about buying / why don't you buy a t-shirt / t-shirts or an item / items that you'll use now **as well**?"

Thanks all for reading.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 'instead' was kindly inserted by the translator because the speaker did *not* use も (=also, as well) in the original sentence. It's the absence of も that implies the speaker is suggesting buying something else instead.

> - 靴(を)買うならTシャツ**も**買っては？
>     If you're going to buy shoes, why don't you buy a T-shirt *as well*?
> - 靴(を)買うならTシャツ(**を**)買っては？
>     If you're going to buy shoes, why don't you buy a T-shirt (instead)?

And this answered your last question, too.