# Issue with figuring out what [どう+なの] correctly translates to in the following sentence

Tags: translation, usage, sentence-final-particles

I have translated most of the following sentence on my own, but I am having great difficulty in understanding then translating the ending of どうなの.

> 教え子の名前ぐらい、もう少し考えたら**どうなの**？

According to nevan king answer at [What exactly is "なの" (nano)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/514/what-exactly-is-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE-nano) ,

> The な is only there if you use it after a noun or a na-adjective (きれい, 大変, 非常).

However, as far as I am aware, according to [https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/どう/#je-52734](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86/#je-52734) and based on the context (shown below), the どう here most likely means "the same". Whether どう is a noun or na-adjective is unknown to me; so I can't accurately use [What exactly is "なの" (nano)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/514/what-exactly-is-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE-nano) to help me understand its meaning.

> しかし、アインにツヴァイか……。
>   教え子の名前ぐらい、もう少し考えたら**どうなの**？

TDLR: What does どうなの mean in the above sentence?

Comment: どう here most likely doesn't mean 'the same'. ⇦ Fixed it for you. What other meaning could どう have? (hint: どうですか？）

Comment: @BJCUAI I am a utter idiot for not remembering the connection that なの has with です and then applying it to my translation. And I remember hearing that どうですか phrase means "How is it?" or variants thereof.

Comment: @ToyuFrey So, going by this realization, do you have a new understanding of what this means? Would you proffer a revised translation of 「もう少し考えたらどうなの？」?

Answer (score 2):

If you have seen 考えてはどうですか before, this 考えたらどうなの is a variation of it. たら is a condition marker, どう is "how", な is the attributive form of the copula, の is ["explanatory-no"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5399/5010) (or a seek-for-clarification marker as explained [here](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/question-markers/)). In general, `conditional + どう/如何 + copula + question marker` (literally "how is it like if you ～") forms a suggestion/advice. (な)の is optional, but it essentially makes the suggestion stronger by adding a little doubtful tone ("I wonder why you don't ～").

There are many variations, each with a different omission/formality/politeness level.

- お考えになっては如何【いかが】でしょうか？ (highly polite)
- 考えてはどうなのですか？
- お考えになっては？ (everything after a condition marker can be omitted)
- 考えては如何？
- 考えたらどう？
- 考えたらどうなん？
- 考えたらどっすか？
- 考えたらどうなのよ？
- 考えたら？

Related:

- [in 買っては, I need some explanation for っては part](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25928/5010)
- [What does たら do at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29766/5010)